# Append output mode not working in Spark Structured streaming with foreach sink

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

For each sink with following definition

```
class CouchBaseSinkForeach() extends ForeachWriter[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] {

override def open(partitionId: Long, version: Long): Boolean = {
 // Open connection

true
}

override def process(value: Row): Unit =
{
   convertRowToJSON(value)
   println("My Test Hi")
}


override def close(errorOrNull: Throwable): Unit = {
   // Close the connection
}
```

is used in following streaming query

```
val streamDf=  records
  .filter($"region"==="US" )
  .withColumn("startTimeEpoch", ud($"startTimeEpoch"))
  .withColumn("startTimeEpoch", $"startTimeEpoch".cast(sql.types.TimestampType))
  .withWatermark("startTimeEpoch", "10 minutes")
  .groupBy(window($"startTimeEpoch","10 minutes","10 minutes"),$"accountId")
     .count()
streamDf.writeStream
  .foreach(new CouchBaseSinkForeach)
  .start()
  .awaitTermination()
```

When in append mode the Spark is not calling back process method. But it calls open method.
Everything works fine when update mode is used.

Is this bug on spark side.? I am using spark streaming 2.4.5

Comment: You should check out `startTimeEpoch` column and see if it progresses and the values get updated. Use `MemorySource` as the input data source to test that out.

Comment: It is working fine for me. It wasn't working for me when my open method was returning false value. But after changing the open method return value to true, process method is getting called for each of the record.